# How to use Proxy PAC file for python urllib or request?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, urllib, pac

How do I include my automatic proxy config file in HTTP libraries like 
urllib or requests.

```
pacfile = 'http://myintranet.com/proxies/ourproxies.pac'
proxy = urllib3.ProxyManager(????????????????)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Current there is no support for a proxy PAC file directly in urllib3 or requests. While support could *in principle* be added for proxy PAC files, because they are Javascript files that require interpretation it is likely to be extremely difficult to provide broad-based support.

In principle you could use requests/urllib3 to request the Proxy PAC file, then pass it to something like Node.JS for interpreting, then parse the results back in Python to pass to urllib3/requests, but nothing like that exists out of the box.

Answer (score 12):

I've created a pure-Python library called [PyPAC](http://pypac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html) which should do what you're looking for. It provides a subclass of `requests.Session` that includes honours PACs and includes PAC auto-discovery.

Comment: How is the best pratice to use pypac in requests?

Comment: i'm tinkering with monkey patching urlllib.   it's the only legit way to cover everything, since you may be using a library that you can't modify, which, in turn, uses requests or urllib or both.

Comment: @ErikAronesty [pypac.pac_context_for_url()](https://pypac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pypac.pac_context_for_url) is a bit of a cheat way to get libraries working under a PAC network, as long as those libraries recognize proxy environment variables. It's not perfect, but it'll get people over the PAC hurdle in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

Use PYPAC.

```
from pypac import PACSession, get_pac

pac = get_pac(url='http://your/pac/url/file.pac')
session = PACSession(pac, proxy_auth=HTTPProxyAuth('your_user', 'password'))
print(session.get('http://www.google.com'))
```

you will get a 200