# How can I download file using pyQt 5 webengine with python script code?

Tags: python, pyqt5

so i want to make auto download when i got some link,
let say the link is : http://test.com/somefile.avi

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QWidgetAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile, QWebEngineDownloadItem, QWebEnginePage


class WebPage(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.load(QUrl("http://test.com"))
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.n = 0

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        print("Finished Loading")
        self.page().toHtml(self.Callable)

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.load(QUrl(userInput))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    userInput = input()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = WebPage()
```

except i only have the page 'test.com', but i cant get the file 'somefile.avi', is it possible to make it autodownload after i input the 'http://test.com/somefile.avi' in console?

Thanks

Comment: I would say yes. However, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i try to read qt the docs at : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-module.html, it mention something about download, but i dont know how to make it works, i'm a beginner python actually.

Comment: You could use the `requests` library. Not Qt, but it works.

Comment: thanks, could you please write the example code with requests? oh, note that i have auto proxy setting in my office, so my workaround is using qt web engine

Comment: Hey, so I added some example code I had lying around from another answer I gave last week, and modified it some to account for your proxy set up. Also note the disclaimer about `PyQt` and `requests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a code snippet of how to do this with the `requests` library

**DISCLAIMER**

*This example was made with `requests`, python 3rd party library, and **not** with PyQt as the asker originally intended.*

```
import requests
import shutil

def download(url):

    # gets the filename from the url, and
    # creates the download file absolute path
    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    path = "downloads/" + filename

    # Defines relevant proxies, see `requests` docs
    proxies = {
      'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
      'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
    }

    # Add proxies, and leave `stream=True` for file downloads
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, proxies=proxies)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    else:
        # Manually raise if status code is anything other than 200
        r.raise_for_status()


download('http://test.com/somefile.avi')
```

Edit:

`pac` files do not work out of the box with any of the common python web request libraries, however, SO user @CarsonLam provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528812/how-to-use-proxy-pac-file-for-python-urllib-or-request) that attempts to solve this issue.

The library `pypac`provides support for this, and since it inherits from `requests` objects, it would macigally work with our existing code. Some additional pac examples can be found [here](http://pypac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html).

With a pac proxy file, I would guess something like this would be the way to go;

```
from pypac import PACSession, get_pac
import shutil

def download(url):

    # gets the filename from the url, and
    # creates the download file absolute path
    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    path = "downloads/" + filename

    # looks for a pac file at the specified url, and creates a session
    # this session inherits from requests.Session
    pac = get_pac(url='http://foo.corp.local/proxy.pac')
    session = PACSession(pac)

    # Add proxies, and leave `stream=True` for file downloads
    session = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    else:
        # Manually raise if status code is anython other than 200
        r.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, however how can i set the auto proxy file (my company use .pac file) i got error : ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',)))

Comment: Wow haha, now you really put me in the spot ;) hang on!

Comment: Okay, so I updated my answer, feel free to get back with how it went! Also big props to @CarsonLam for providing this.

Comment: so in this line : session = requests.get(url, stream=True, proxies=proxies), i try proxies to pac, it got error. could you please help me on this?

Comment: Yeah sure, it shouldn't use `proxies=proxies`. I updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: it works on local net, cool,  however not on world site : i got error requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 407 Client Error: Proxy Authentication Required for url: http://google.com/, thanks alot. it would be great if it can be bypassed. note that i already set auth following this: http://pypac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#proxy-authentication

Comment: Look the documentation of `pypac`, there are some options on how to authenticate with a pac proxy. You are welcome!

Comment: ah, yes, i got it, but not work, but thanks anyway :)